# How to parse json object with different key values?

Tags: java, json, android-volley

We are trying to parse an json object which is having different key-values everytime.

```
{
  "Key1": "Val1",
  "Key2": "Val2",
  "Key3": "Val3",
  "Key4": "Val4",
  "Key5": "Val5",
  .........,
  .........,
  "KeyN": "ValN"
}
```

Here `"KeyN"` can have different names also `"ValueN"` also will be different.

It is very clear that this will not parse in one go, like :

```
ObjectX objetX = new Gson().fromJson(sourceJson, ObjectX.class);
```

How should we parse this ? even if we choose to parse manually ? We trying this in android Volley response.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Using Gson java library parse your json object into `HashMap<String,String>`.

> sample code

```
     sourceJson = {
  "Key1": "Val1",
  "Key2": "Val2",
  "Key3": "Val3",
  "Key4": "Val4",
  "Key5": "Val5",
  .........,
  .........,
  "KeyN": "ValN"
};

        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(sourceJson, type);
```

If you want more generic solution should be

```
Map map = gson.fromJson(sourceJson, Map.class);
```